# Register FiddlerCore as a ProxyInProcess and modify https traffic calling CreateProxyEndpoint.

Tags: c#, fiddler, fiddlercore

I have a issue using FiddlerCore to modify https traffic after starting fiddler with the following. I pass in the port, upstream proxy and bypassAddress if set.
I have tried passing in "*" and "127.0.0.1" and even the certificate by calling CertMaker.GetRootCertificate() and passing in the certificate in FiddlerApplication.CreateProxyEndpoint and the result is not null, but my https traffic isnt logged.

```
    internal static void StartProxyWithSecureEndPoint(int proxyPort, string upstreamProxy, string bypassAddress)
    {
        ProxyPort = proxyPort;
        UpstreamProxy = upstreamProxy;
        BypassAddress = bypassAddress;

        _upstreamProxy = upstreamProxy;
        URLMonInterop.SetProxyInProcess("127.0.0.1:" + proxyPort, bypassAddress);
        CONFIG.IgnoreServerCertErrors = true;
        CONFIG.bCaptureCONNECT = false;

        if (_upstreamProxy == null)
        {
            _fiddlerOptions = (FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default & ~FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.RegisterAsSystemProxy  & ~FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.CaptureFTP & ~FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.ChainToUpstreamGateway);
        }
        else
        {
            _fiddlerOptions = (FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default & ~FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.RegisterAsSystemProxy & ~FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.CaptureFTP);
        }


        FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest += FiddlerApplication_BeforeRequest;
        FiddlerApplication.BeforeResponse += FiddlerApplication_BeforeResponse;
        FiddlerApplication.ResponseHeadersAvailable += FiddlerApplication_ResponseHeadersAvailable;
        FiddlerApplication.OnValidateServerCertificate += FiddlerApplication_OnValidateServerCertificate;

        FiddlerApplication.Startup(proxyPort, _fiddlerOptions);
        _secureEndpoint = FiddlerApplication.CreateProxyEndpoint(proxyPort, false, "*");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `"*"` isn't a valid value for a certificate hostname in your call to `CreateProxyEndpoint`.
2. When you call `CreateProxyEndpoint` and pass a certificate hostname, the listener you create doesn't behave like a proxy, it behaves like a HTTPS server. As a consequence, if you use `SetProxyInProcess` to force WinINET callers in your process to send traffic to that endpoint, the requests will all fail because the client will send a `CONNECT` to something that's expecting a HTTPS ClientHello.
3. When you set `bCaptureCONNECT` to `false`, you prevent the client from trying to proxy its secure traffic.

From your textual description of what you're trying to do, you shouldn't be calling `CreateProxyEndpoint` at all, and you should not be setting `bCaptureCONNECT` either. And just to confirm, because you're not setting `RegisterAsSystemProxy`, you'll *only* be capturing traffic from WinINET callers (e.g. a WebBrowserControl) inside your own process.

Have you had a look at the Program.cs demo that ships with the FiddlerCore download?

Comment: Thanks for that Eric. The * was something I found whilst trying to see how to correctly set the Proxy. I bought your book Friday as well, but I seem to be missing something very obvious. I have a internal browser that I set to use the fiddler proxy when i have created it and only capture traffic from the browser control. I've changed * to localhost, removed the bCaptureCONNECT but i still only can see http traffic. Could you perhaps give me a small sample of how to capture all traffic for the app. I have installed the certificate.

Comment: `Program.cs` included with FiddlerCore will capture all traffic including secure traffic. Based on the most common causes of errors, I'm betting you don't have makecert.exe located in the right folder. Be sure to sync the `OnNotification` and `OnLogString` events to get helpful error messages.

Comment: @EricLaw Hi Eric, I have been struggling with FiddlerCore, and in spite of looking at the sample app and many posts, I cannot get it working. I realize you are not at Telerik anymore, but if you still answer FiddlerCore questions, I have posted one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39882846/using-fiddlercore-in-a-c-sharp-application-to-capture-a-single-https-request-and)