# Using FiddlerCore in a C# application to capture a single HTTPS Request and Response which the app itself provokes

Tags: https, fiddlercore

I am writing a C# .NET 4.0 application in which I navigate a WebBrowser control to a secure website, programmatically enter the credentials, and navigate to a particular page. I want to capture the HTTPS requests and responses which result from the single click of a button, something like this:

```
    NavigateControlToWebPage("https://fancyDancySite.com/fancyPage");
    IHTMLElement btn = doc.getElementById("fancyDancyButton");
    StartCapturingMyOwnHTTPSStuffWithFiddlerCore();
    btn.click();
    StopTheCapturing();
```

I have been messing with this based on a number of examples on the web, and with using the SampleApp for FiddlerCore. I am simply not able to decipher how to do what the StartCapturing method needs to do. My code currently is this, but it does not succeed:

```
WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy();
Uri newUri = new Uri("https://localhost:8080");
myProxy.Address = newUri;

if (!Fiddler.CertMaker.rootCertExists())
{
    if (!Fiddler.CertMaker.createRootCert())
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to create cert for FiddlerCore.");
    }
}
if (!Fiddler.CertMaker.rootCertIsTrusted())
{
    if (!Fiddler.CertMaker.trustRootCert())
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to install FiddlerCore's cert.");
    }
}
Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(8080, Fiddler.FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.DecryptSSL);

Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete += Fiddler_AfterSessionComplete;
```

ETA: I am behind a corporate proxy, trying to access an external https site.

ETA: I am having some effect, because the webbrowser control gets a "Navigation was cancelled" page instead of the usual website. But that is not the effect I want :)

ETA: removed the SetProxyInProcess which I think is not appropriate in this case

ETA: My current StartCapturing method is as follows:

```
    public void StartCapturingMyOwnHTTPSStuffWithFiddlerCore()
    {
        InstallCertificate();
        FiddlerApplication.Startup(0, FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default);
        FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete += Fiddler_AfterSessionComplete;
    }
```

This works, but when I add `& ~RegisterAsSystemProxy` it stops working.

Answer (score 1):

All of your code for `WebProxy myProxy` is not needed because this is the code used to set the Web Proxy for System.NET's HTTPWebRequests, but the Web Browser control does not use the System.NET HTTP Stack, it uses WinINET's stack.

The `StartupFlags` you're setting are not sufficient; you should use `FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default` instead if you want to capture traffic from all applications, or use `FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default & ~FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.RegisterAsSystemProxy` if you plan to use the SetProxyInProcess API to get traffic only from your current application.

You need to be very very careful in how your "StopTheCapturing" code is implemented, because it's very likely that you're calling it far too early-- the call to click the button in the Web Browser Control will return almost instantly, but the Web Browser control will likely be performing operations for some period of time afterward.

Comment: Thanks Eric. If I flag `Default & ~RegisterAsSystemProxy` then I do not get `Fiddler_AfterSessionComplete` events firing. I do want to get HTTPS sessions originating with requests from within the application. I never did get `SetProxyInProcess` working. How do I do that? The examples I found online did not work for me. (edit: As for the "StopCapture", that is well timed within the actual source code, that was just a four-line example of what I wanted.)

Comment: How specifically did you call `SetProxyInProcess`? It should be called like e.g. ` Fiddler.URLMonInterop.SetProxyInProcess("127.0.0.1:7777", "<-loopback>");` if your proxy is running on port `7777`.

Comment: "if your proxy is running on port 7777"... not sure which proxy you mean by "your" proxy? I am unclear on what steps I need to take in order to capture within the application only the HTTPS traffic that the application itself is generating.

Comment: FiddlerCore is a proxy that runs inside your application. Looking at your code, you picked port 8080, so the call should be `Fiddler.URLMonInterop.SetProxyInProcess("127.0.0.1:8080", "<-loopback>");`

Comment: I now have:
`FiddlerApplication.Startup(8080, FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default & ~FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.RegisterAsSystemProxy);`
`Fiddler.URLMonInterop.SetProxyInProcess("127.0.0.1:8080", "<-loopback>");`
`FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete += Fiddler_AfterSessionComplete;`
but this is still not working. I get a "navigation failed" response. I suspect it is ignoring the system proxy (corporate), through which all external internet traffic must pass?

Comment: Actually, this code is OVERWRITING my system proxy.

Comment: I don't know what `overwriting` means in this context, or how you're testing. What output do you get from logging in the AfterSessionComplete handler?

Comment: By "overwriting" I mean that when I check my LAN proxy setting in Internet Explorer, the corporate proxy has been replaced with 127.0.0.1, port 8080. After calling `SetProxyInProcess` I am unable to navigate the browser control, and no `AfterSessionComplete` handler occurs.

Comment: Hook `BeforeRequest` to see if you're even getting traffic. `SetProxyInProcess` doesn't touch the system proxy; what's more likely is you didn't cleanup the proxy settings back when you didn't have `~FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.RegisterAsSystemProxy` in your startup flags. Without your app running, fix the settings in IE.

Comment: I did the following, and this worked. Apparently the ports I was picking were disabled, so I let FiddlerCore pick the port:

`FiddlerApplication.Startup(0, FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default & ~FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.RegisterAsSystemProxy);`
`Fiddler.URLMonInterop.SetProxyInProcess("127.0.0.1:" + FiddlerApplication.oProxy.ListenPort.ToString(), "<-loopback>");`
`FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete += Fiddler_AfterSessionComplete;`
`FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest += Fiddler_BeforeRequest;`

However, now I am getting prompted about installing and uninstalling root certificates?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't really meant to be used in this way (questions as comments). The issue with certificates is likely because you're using the BouncyCastle cert maker instead of the default; see https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/jul/29/using-fiddlercore-to-capture-http-requests-with-net for discussion.